DBATools Export-DbaDbTableData and single quotes
I've got the following PowerShell script to export specific tables from a database using dbatools and Export-DbaDbTableData. I do this as part of some automation.
# Define your parameters
...

#SQL Auth
$username = ""
$password = ""
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)


Set-DbatoolsInsecureConnection -SessionOnly

# Loop through each table
foreach ($table in $tables) {

Write-Host "Starting Table $table."

    # Get the table data
    $tableData = Get-DbaDbTable -SqlInstance $sqlInstance -Database $database -SqlCredential $credential -Table $table
    
    # Define the output file path with the table name
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath "$table.sql"
    
    # Export the table data to the file
    $tableData | Export-DbaDbTableData -FilePath $filePath
    
}

Write-Host "Data export completed."

It works and exports to a SQL file as expected. However, I'm having an issue where it will not escape single quotes in data. So I end up with a SQL insert statement that may break the eventual import, so something like this;
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES ('O'Reilly');

Which can turn up wherever in the full SQL export, then it fails on import, whereas I believe I need this
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES ('O''Reilly');

I've had a look and I think it's because dbatools doesn't 'parameterize' the values. I can export manually from SSMS using the generate scripts for each table and that does escape it as expected - but I can't automate this. Any suggestions on what I can do with dbatools or other scripts to get around this and keep it automated?

My suggestion would be a bit out of Box. Once it is exported, you use regular expressions to handle the String like you normally handle strings and then overwrite the file. That way, you dont need to handle it in the db parameters.

Is your DBATools out of date? I just tried using Export-DbaDbTableData and it exported the INSERT statements with properly escaped quotes: INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([SomeString]) VALUES (N'I''m a string')

@RanadipDutta that would be a bad idea, sql code cannot be reliably matched by regex

@ThomA Interesting - the server is running 2.1.17, so a couple of minor version out of date. I'll run some tests locally with the latest version.

I'm still running 2.1.3 (as my work PC doesn't update it automatically). I'll update as well to double check it it's not a regression.

Just tried it on 2.1.23; strings were still properly escaped.

Yes, i've tried it locally and it seems to work. Going to get it updated on the server and see if that resolves it. Thanks.

Seems to be working on the server with 2.1.23. Thanks @ThomA

@ThomA: It depends on the version I believe. Replying to your comment if peter's DBATools out of date. I remember that I suffered something similar 3 years back.

Yeah, the fact that I couldn't replicate in 2.1.3, and it doesn't occur in 2.1.23 suggests that it was a regression in or around the release of 2.1.17, @RanadipDutta .

Updating DBATools version from 2.1.17 to 2.1.23 seems to have sorted it. Perhaps an issue with that release.
